# Sorting & Merging Java ArrayList like Python Tuples

Tags: java, python, arraylist, tuples

I am from Python background, currently porting my Python program to Java. I need suggestion on best approach to solve a problem.

Originally, I created a list of tuples in Python :

```py
loft = [('india',1),('accepts',1),('narendra',1), ('modi',1),('manmohan',1),('singh',1),('sonia gandhi',1),('rajkot',1),('sharma',1),('raja',1),('india',2),('manmohan',2),('singh',2),('nepal',2),('prime minister',2),('meeting',2),('economy',2),('manmohan',3),('narendra',3),('modi',3),('gupta',3),('rajkot',3),('patel',3),('singh',3),('rajiv',3),('aajtak',3),('manmohan',4),('nepal',4),('bahadur',4),('king',4),('meeting',4),('economy',4),('wife',4),('plane',4)]
```

(where india,accepts are keyword and numbers are id taken from database.).
Now, applying :

```py
di = {}
for x,y in ll:
     di.setdefault(x,[]).append(y)
newdi = {}
```

My list becomes a dictionary:

```py
di = {'manmohan': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'sonia gandhi': [1], 'raja': [1], 'india': [1, 2], 'narendra': [1, 3], 'patel': [3], 'sharma': [1], 'nepal': [2, 4], 'gupta': [3], 'singh': [1, 2, 3], 'meeting': [2, 4], 'economy': [2, 4], 'rajkot': [1, 3], 'prime minister': [2], 'plane': [4], 'bahadur': [4], 'king': [4], 'wife': [4], 'accepts': [1], 'modi': [1, 3], 'aajtak': [3], 'rajiv': [3]}
```

#### Java Part:

```java
    public void step1() throws SQLException{

      Connection con= new Clustering().connect();

      Statement st = con.createStatement();
      Statement st1 = con.createStatement();
      ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select uid from url where artorcat=1");

      ArrayList<Tuples> allkeyword = new ArrayList<Tuples>();
      long starttime = System.currentTimeMillis();

      while (rs.next()) {
        int id = rs.getInt("uid");
        String query = "select tags.tagname from tags left join tag_url_relation on tags.tid=tag_url_relation.tid where tag_url_relation.uid="+id;
        ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery(query);
        while (rs1.next()){
          String tag = rs1.getString(1);

          //Creating an object t of type Tuples
          //and pass values to constructor
          Tuples t = new Tuples(id,tag);
          //adding the above tuple to arraylist allkeyword
          allkeyword.add(t);
        }//job done, now lets test by iterating
      }

      Iterator<Tuples> it = allkeyword.iterator();
      while(it.hasNext()){

        Tuples t = it.next();
        System.out.println(t.getId());
        System.out.println(t.getKeyword());
      }

      long endtime = System.currentTimeMillis();
      long totaltime = endtime-starttime;
      System.out.println("Total time:" + totaltime);
    }


And here is Tuples class : 

/**
 * 
 * 
 * Tuple class is created to create a multiple data type tuple. We are using this tuples object to retrieve keyword and 
 * id in step1 in Clustering.java.
 * @author akshayy
 *
 */


public class Tuples {
    int i;
    String s;


    public Tuples(int i, String s) {
        this.i= i;
        this.s=s;
    }


    public int getId(){
        return this.i;
    }

    public String getKeyword(){
        return this.s;      
    }


}
```

So far so good. I am created an arraylist of tuple class that contain keyword and id. Now what about next step of finding occurrence of keyword in id. like 'manmohan' is found in id 1,2,3,4 and so on.

```py
di = {'manmohan': [1, 2, 3, 4], 'sonia gandhi': [1], 'raja': [1], 'india': [1, 2], 'narendra': [1, 3], 'patel': [3], 'sharma': [1], 'nepal': [2, 4], 'gupta': [3], 'singh': [1, 2, 3], 'meeting': [2, 4], 'economy': [2, 4], 'rajkot': [1, 3], 'prime minister': [2], 'plane': [4], 'bahadur': [4], 'king': [4], 'wife': [4], 'accepts': [1], 'modi': [1, 3], 'aajtak': [3], 'rajiv': [3]}
```

Please suggest me what should be next approach to find similar items in arraylist and sorting them like above. Or do I need a totally different thing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would need to create a Map with List or Set values. Depending on your need, you may keep the Tuples class or just use String and Integer separately.

Here is an example:

```
// construct a map with string key (tag) and list of integers (ids) as the value
Map<String, List<Integer>> keywords = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();

while (rs.next()) {
    int id = rs.getInt("uid");
    String query = "select tags.tagname from tags left join tag_url_relation on tags.tid=tag_url_relation.tid where tag_url_relation.uid="+id;
    ResultSet rs1 = st1.executeQuery(query);

    while (rs1.next()){
        String tag = rs1.getString(1);

        // construct the List for this keyword
        if (!keywords.containsKey(tag)) {
            keywords.put(tag, new ArrayList<Integer>());
        } 
        keywords.get(tag).add(id);
    }
}
```

`keywords` will be a data structure similar to what you have in your Python implementation:

```
List<Integer> manmohanList = keywords.get("manmohan"); // will get you a list containing the numbers 1,2,3,4
for (Integer id: manmohanList) {
    System.out.println(id); // prints 1,2,3,4
}
```

Comment: thanks. what if I have to apply this on large datasets. any performance concerns? I would like to go as native as possible to speed up.

Comment: An ArrayList instance's size grows with the number of elements inside it. If there is not enough space, it will create another backing array double the previous size, and the contents of the old backing array will be copied to the new backing array. To optimize, you need to set up a good initial size for the ArrayList, for example: `new ArrayList<Integer>(1000000)` so that you can avoid that doubling up and copying.

Comment: A HashMap works in a similar way, but instead of just size, you need to set up both size (meaning number of keys) and load factor. For a HashMap with size 100 and load factor 0.75, it will increase in size when the 75th element is inserted. Therefore, you need to set appropriate values for the size and load factor of the HashMap depending on the amount of data you expect.

Comment: For accesses, HashMap with String key is as fast as you can get.

Comment: I have to apply an algorithm, whose first step is this. number of keywords are growing and growing.I have million keywords and need to perform several operations on them. seems like this is a good start. HashMap are good enough for large datasets if number is predetermined which can be.  thnx.

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the java.lang.Map interface. You essentially are building a

```
Map<String,List<Integer>>
```

Using pure Collections classes, you can use such methods as contains and Collections.sort (watch performance if that is a concern, you may consider your own sorting algorithm if needed)

Iterating over a Map is not as straight forward for a new Java developer, but you can iterate over the KeySet, do a get on the map at each iteration point, and then do a contains on the value which in this case is a List.

```
Integer bar = whatever you are evaluating
Map<String, List<Integer>> fooMap = new HashMap<String, List<Integer>>();
... build your map ...
for(String key:fooMap.keySet()){
    if(fooMap.get(key).contains(bar)){
        ...logic when found...  
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. in general, I need to look Collections for such data structure operations.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than having a class for tupples you should better declare a HashMap for storing your dictionary keywords and positions. Such as

```
Map<String, ArrayList<Integer>> dictionary = new HashMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>>();

//Now before adding any new keyword to the map just check if it contains it or not.
while (rs1.next()){
   //Your
   //Old
   //Code
   if(dictionary.contains(tag)){
       id_list = dictionary.get(tag);
       id_list.add(id);
       dictionary.put(tag, id_list);
   }else{
        dictionary.put(tag, id);
   }
}
```

haven't tested it for typo errors. But i guess you should get an idea. hope that helps.

Comment: I am building a high performance application, need to iterate every half an hour on large data sets. I heard HashMap is slow, is it so?

Comment: Well I never used it on a high scale but it could be slow for get method as it iterates over a large map to find a particular value for given key (in your case i afraid it can be comparatively slow). But Java is not Python :P so for language processing you might will have to compromise. Also this is the best option you should go with.

Comment: Thanks. threading is also not applicable in this case, to speed up.